# Is there a common name for a function satisfying $f(X) \le f(Y)$ implies $f(X \cup Z) \le f(Y \cup Z)$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory, terminology

I have a real-valued function $f$ on subsets of a domain $\Omega$ satisfying for all $X, Y, Z \subset \Omega$, if $f(X) \le f(Y)$, then $f(X \cup Z) \le f(Y \cup Z)$. I would like to look up more existing literature on functions like this. Does anyone know what such functions are called?

My function is also monotone (for all $X \subset Y \subset \Omega$, we have $f(X) \le f(Y)$), so if there is an existing term that refers to functions that are both monotone and satisfying the above, that would be great as well. My domain $\Omega$ is finite, if that matters. Thank you!

To give a non-trivial example of such a function, consider any $g : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and set $f(X) = \sum_{x \in X} g(x)$. This is monotone and satisfies the desired condition.

Comment: @MathNeophyte $f$ is a function $\mathcal P(\Omega) \to \mathbb R$

Comment: Woops I deleted my comment since I made a mistake in it and was gonna rewrite something but thanks for clarifying. So you are stating $f(x) \leq f(y)$ for all $x \in X \cup Z$ and $y \in Y \cup Z$ in the ordering of the codomain

Comment: But if you consider $X = Y = \varnothing$ you get $f(Z) \leq f(Z)$ which would imply your function is constant on $Z$, no? Depending on how you are choosing elements in the comparison

Comment: Oh nvm I see what it means ok the domain is actually the sets

Comment: @JonathanHole That's not correct, with $Z = \emptyset$ we get $f(X) \le f(Y)$ implies $f(X) \le f(Y)$, which is just trivially true, not equivalent to being monotone.

Comment: Your example is one of these btw, Glenn https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-additive_set_function

Comment: If you define it to be 0 on the empty set then it becomes a measure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)

Comment: The example you provided is **a modular (linear) set function**. Do you have another example that is not modular?